# Boost error (segmentation fault) simple_segregated_storage.hpp

Tags: c++, boost, segmentation-fault

Im compiling the source code of an old game server, the compilation runs without errors, but when I try to execute the output I get a segmentation fault.
I recompiled with -g flag and executed gdb with the following

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000414004 in boost::simple_segregated_storage<unsigned long>::segregate (block=0xeaf3d0, sz=0, partition_sz=8, end=0x0)
    at /usr/local/include/boost-1_55/boost/pool/simple_segregated_storage.hpp:304
304         nextof(iter) = old;
```

I tried to change the boost's version from 1_65_1 to 1_55 but still getting that error.
Any idea?

Comment: I'd use my programming skills to fix the problem. Please, seriously, start with the [tour] and read [ask]. In order to turn your question into a valid one, extract a [mcve] from the failing code and post that here. BTW: Downgrading to an even older version is usually not going to help.

Comment: My experience with boost is that SIGSEGV somewhere inside boost is nearly always due to something I did earlier (bad memory management).

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting same error. within segregate method its trying to get next pointer address somehow the iterator position and partition size is not in sync , which causes to access invalid address (Segmentation Fault.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33703489)